# Null Pointer Exception for android widget EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am getting a the error in the onClick method when the EditText object is referenced.

```
public class messageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText editText;
  Button button;
  Logic logic;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logic.message(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

---

Here is the XML for the `EditText` widget in my activity:

```
<EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
      android:inputType="textShortMessage"
      android:editable="false" />
```

Comment: where do you initialize your Logic variable? this would seem to be the null pointer here. please post your logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspecting that `Logic` is one of your classes? You are getting `NullPointerException` because the variable `logic` is not initialized with a value - you need to instantiate logic before you do `logic.message`.

Comment: Yep, that was it...don't know how I missed that,duh. Thanks for the the help!

Comment: Great! Very easy to miss these ones - I am glad this helped, simple fix! Please do accept the answer to be marked as answered.